# Writing into model using devise variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have model, and when i write into it, i'm using standart `Model.create!(params[:somesymbol])`
However in my form i have hidden field with `current_user.id`
`current_user` its variable from devise, which returns user that is logged. So when i create new record, i believe to user, that he didnt change value in hidden field. Is there any ways to avoid this, and write into model in some way like this 
`Model.create!(params[:somesymbol], user_id: current_user.id)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
Model.create!(params[:somesymbol].merge(user_id: current_user.id))
```

The `user_id` in `params` will be overridden by `current_user.id` (see [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge))